# Using function within function with parameters as tuples

Tags: python

I want to create a function that takes in the following tuples a and b, and use a function that I had already created (cost) to add them together. For my question, it doesn't matter what cost() does.

Cost has the following arguments (name, amount, extra, team).  Say someone provided me with a and b with the first 3 tuples.  If they don't provide team, I will just assume team = 1

a=('John', 20, 5)
b=('Matt', 30, 7)

```
def totalamount(a, b):
    a=(name, amount, extra, 1)
    b=(sign, amount, extra, 1)
    total=cost(u)+cost(v)
    return total
```

The error is saying I'm missing the required positional arguments.  Can someone help me on what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably `total=cost(*u)+cost(*v)`.

Comment: Note that `a=(name, amount, extra, team=1)` is invalid Python (a `SyntaxError`).

Comment: Ah thanks for catching that.

Comment: cost(*u) +cost(*v). thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, you are having errors because `(name, amount, extra)` are not defined in the function `totalamount`, in addition to the syntax error.

One workaround is to check the length of the tuples `a` and `b`. If they are of length 3, then `team` is not provided, otherwise it is. Note that we are assuming that 3 and 4 are the only possible lengths for `a` and `b`.

```
def totalamount(a, b):
    a = a + (1,) if len(a) == 3 else a
    b = b + (1,) if len(b) == 3 else b
    total = cost(*a) + cost(*b)
    return total
```